# Asynchronous loading of multiple JS files by Zombie

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom, zombie.js

Trying Zombie for a few first hours and being way excited. The only (begginner's luck?) problem is that the scripts are seemed to be loaded asynchronously (which is cool) and executed in the order they were downloaded (and not in the order they are mentioned in the "original" HTML file). I will explain:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>alert($('body'))</script>
</head>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/GWYEj/ - the following script loads jQuery and tries to use it. It takes time to download the jQuery, but Zombie seems to proceed to the next script section ahead the downloading is completed. Obviously, there is no much meaning to $('body') without jQuery, hence we are getting the following error:

```
Zombie: GET http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/GWYEj/show/
Zombie: GET http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/GWYEj/show/ => 200
Zombie: GET http://jsfiddle.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.4.js
Zombie: GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js
Zombie: GET http://jsfiddle.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.4.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token } SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Object._evaluate (/home/viebel/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/browser.coffee:136:28)
    in http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/GWYEj/show/:undefined:undefined<script>
Zombie: GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js => 200
```

In "regular" browser the code works fluently. Yes, we know that node.js isn't really client-side javascript, but Zombie.js shoudld be, isn't it?

Please assist what are we doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like theres a syntax error in mootools core. Also your loading both mootools and jQuery on the same page (this is stupid)

Comment: I have the exact problem right now. The issue (not sure if it's right) seems to be in the zombie/lib/xhr.js file. The xhr open API implementation ignores the async parameter sent in. It doesn't seem to do anything.